# Hypergeometric distribution by phyper

Tags: r, testing, probability

I have a question about calculating the hypergeometric test using `phyper` package.

I have two sets of random names and a number that shows the overlap:

```
the number of names in set A: 488
the number of names in set B: 312
the number of overlap between the two sets: 16
```

I want to calculate if `the number of overlap between the two sets` is significant or is by chance?

How can I perform this by having `ONLY` three values as input?

Thank you

Comment: I can't see any basis for this test.  You need to know how many names are possible:  if there are only 488 names in the universe, the overlap is impossibly low.  If there are a billion names in the universe, the overlap is astoundingly high.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. If there is a total of 25000 names then how this could be calculated?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, please avoid cross-posting the same questions on several platforms (https://www.biostars.org/p/9488943/).

Secondly, to do such enrichment test, there is no need to implement it yourself; check out RVenn::enrichment_test (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/RVenn/versions/1.1.0/topics/enrichment_test). It implements a bootstrap-based hypergeometric test. However, like @user2554330 states, be careful defining the universe (the complete set from which setA and setB were chosen from).